# Wordpress FB plugin missing comments box

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, comments

I was using the Facebook Comments for Wordpress plugin and had FB comments working perfectly for my posts. I switched to the new [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) and everything works but the comments.

When I check my HTML source of my post pages I find the comments section empty. I know I'm missing something just don't know what it is. My site is [cops.com](http://www.cops.com/cops-season-25-crew-pics/) and there should be comments on every post.

Comment: Try and remove, then readd the Facebook plugin. If not, then try and remove the share button that is above it and see if it is causing conflict.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried removing the plugin and even removed all data in the SQL data base and re-installed the plugin fresh. I also disabled DIG DIG plugin which disabled the share icon and still no comment box.

Comment: It looks like in the HTML source for the page, that a reference to to the FB comments is missing. I see class="fb-like fb-social-plugin" for the like button and class="fb-send fb-social-plugin" for the send button but no reference to the comments.. How would I add this.. Sorry I am a complete amateur at this.

Comment: No worries. It sounds like there is a setting in the plugin on wordpress. I don't think I have a wordpress instalment anymore so I can't test this. I will just see if I can install wordpress easily on my localhost and test that for you. Will update later.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress plugin includes the functionality for comments. So there could be a clash that is occurring with your personal implementation of the plugin.

Go to the settings and enable the comments and disable your implementation (unless it is custom).

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=facebook-settings

[image: Comments enabled]

I *believe* only one admin can/should be in control of these settings, there is one variable holding this information in the WP database so if two admins are in, one can overwrite the settings of another.

Also you have two instances of the SDK

`<script type="text/javascript">window.fbAsyncInit=function(){FB.init({"appId":"293125297449760","channelUrl":"http:\/\/www.cops.com\/?fb-channel-file=1","status":true,"cookie":true,"xfbml":true,"oauth":true});}</script>`

and

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '293125297449760', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.cops.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks phwd, WP comments are off and comments is checked in the FB plugin as shown above.

Comment: @ZachRagsdale you still have some clashing going on "FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem"

Comment: I was able to find the second instance but not the first. from the HTML it looks like it's in a style php or css file. But can't locate it. I know when I installed the first plugin FB comments for WP I had to paste some code but can't remember what file i changed it in.

Comment: I removed the second instance.

Comment: Can't find how to remove the first instance

Comment: Ok so I deleted the FB plugin as well as deleted all fb_ in my SQL database. That removed all instances of the SDK. Then I re-installed the plugin. Still no FB comments showing. So the conflict is coming from somewhere else. Any ideas??

Comment: I noticed that when you click the send button in the first row the popup window is masked by the container. When I view the HTMLDivElement I see that the container has a clientHeight: 660 however i think this is a variable height but it is not adjusting for the FB content. How to I change the value of that container to see if it is masking the FB comments box? The page I am working on is here [link] (http://www.cops.com/cs25p7/) Thanks

Comment: I figured it out.... If I select All Posts... then select Quick edit... Then check Allow Comments.. The FB comments section shows up... I don't see the allow comments when I view the single post.. Only in Quick edits

Comment: @ZachRagsdale check wp-admin/options-discussion.php (i.e Settings >> Discussion) ensure "Allow people to post comments on new articles" is enabled in "Default article settings"

Answer (score 1):

If anything else work for you you can try with this other plugin

http://mydibbler.com/fbGroupPoster.html

This will help you build up more likes and share of your page in FB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that the comments weren't appearing. First the comment about editing all Pages to ['Allow Comments'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073261/wordpress-fb-plugin-missing-comments-box#comment14527918_11074240) for all pages was very useful, which pointed in me in the right direction.

My problem was actually that the theme I was using wasn't including comments in the page.php in the theme.

In my theme the `comments_template` wordpress function was missing inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

So I had to add `<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>` to the following code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // begin 'The Loop' ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    ...
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // End 'The Loop' ?>
```